# How to create matrix survey use swift?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I already done to create UI layout for matrix survey, But how to make it only answer one each row?

please correct my code to make it only one answer each row allowed.
here is the view controller that i create, i made the row looping programmaticaly.

[image: http://i61.tinypic.com/nzpoc8.png]

here is my swift code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as QMultiOptionCell

    let idx = indexPath.row
    if selectedAnswers.containsObject(idx) {
        cell.option1CheckImgView.image = UIImage(named: "circledot_uns")
        cell.option2CheckImgView.image = UIImage(named: "circledot_uns")
        cell.option3CheckImgView.image = UIImage(named: "circledot_uns")
        cell.option4CheckImgView.image = UIImage(named: "circledot_uns")
        cell.option5CheckImgView.image = UIImage(named: "circledot_uns")
        selectedAnswers.removeObject(idx)
    } else {
        cell.option1CheckImgView.image = UIImage(named: "circledot")
        cell.option2CheckImgView.image = UIImage(named: "circledot")
        cell.option3CheckImgView.image = UIImage(named: "circledot")
        cell.option4CheckImgView.image = UIImage(named: "circledot")
        cell.option5CheckImgView.image = UIImage(named: "circledot")
        selectedAnswers.addObject(idx)
    }
    cell.selected = false
}
```

here is the error screenshot. when i clicked one circledot, all circledot become active:
[image: http://i57.tinypic.com/97pij9.png]

that code makes all circledots answered together, i just want each row answered only one circledot like Matrix of Choices (One Answer Allowed) in http://www.surveymonkey.com/r/?sm=DnPrQVbiWt6RgarN6lUkkQ%3d%3d did.
regards.

Comment: You want to select one option from a cell right ?

Comment: right, when i click a circledot in a row, the other circledot become circledot_uns. but i think my code problem is, that is code for a row. if a circledot in that row clicked, other circledot in that row (same row) become circledot too (active). i hope a help to repair that code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't implement the intended behavior with current implementation.

#### Issue 1

In your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` your are setting all buttons on a specific cell, so every cell in a selected row will be selected due to this code.

#### Issue 2

You can't easily use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` for this purpose, because you can't know in which button user tapped (For this you need to calculated the touch location and find the button).

#### Solution:

Instead of relying on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` add an action for the buttons added in the cell. When user click on the button, find the cell (using the `superView` property) and then the `indexPath` for that cell (using the `UITableViewCell`, you got from previous step). If that indexPath is not in your array, then previous cell button should be cleared (Can use the same code), then select the button that was clicked (using sender argument of your button action). If that `indexPath` is in your array, then clear all button selection first and then choose the clicked button.

Comment: could you please explain your solution in code? because i did not understand

Comment: @user1858725: In which area you are having issue ?

Comment: in here: add an action for the buttons added in the cell. When user click on the button, find the cell (using the superView property) and then the indexPath for that cell (using the UITableViewCell, you got from previous step), did you mean use button instead of uiimage?

Comment: @user1858725: Create an IBAction for all those buttons (Same method for all)

Comment: like this: @IBAction func tombol1change(sender: UIButton) {
        println(1)
        sender.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "circledot"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as QMultiOptionCell
            
            let idx = indexPath.row
            cell.selected = false
        }
    }
now everytime i click button it become circledot but when i clicked same button it stay as circledot (not circledot_uns).

Comment: @user1858725: You need to write code for deselecting

Comment: how to deselecting? and if i clicked button number 1, i want to button number 2,3,4,5 still use UIImage(named: "circledot_uns"), how to did that mr.midhun?

Comment: @user1858725: I asked you, instead of didselectRowAtIndexPath: write code in that IBAction. I asked you to first find in which cell the button is located and what is the indePath for that cell. (Mentioned the ways in above answer). Then I asked you to implement selecting and deselecting based on the indexPath and clicked button. If you have sample app, I can check and help. I can't explain more on this. Because it's too broad